# One company two domains for two countries - Google Search

Tags: seo, google-search-console, multiple-domains, internationalization, google-business

My company has two domains:
  - www.company.pe (for Peru)
  - www.company.ar (for Argentina)

www.company.com was already taken so i had to buy one domain for each country.

These two sites have pretty similar content but the "spanish is different" for each site.

The problem is about Google Search, when I search "company" in Peru, it shows "www.company.pe" .But when i do the same in Argentina is showing again "www.company.pe" . I tried using cr=countryAR as parameter and only with that way "www.example.ar" appears in the result.

I think the problem is that in Google Business i added the website www.company.pe as my company's site. I added both sites in Google Webmaster Tools and set the target for each to the belonging country, but it's not working.

So, is there a way to tell Google that both belongs to the same company? So it serves the correct domain depending of where i search. Or is something else i can do to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use hreflangs so Google knows which site is for which country.

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://es.example.com/" />`

As stated here: 
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en